# What runlevel should ufw firewall start at in Alpine Linux?

Tags: firewall, ufw, alpine, runlevel

I am using `ufw` on Alpine linux.

I have configured it in a pretty standard way:

```
apk add --no-cache ufw
ufw allow ssh
ufw allow http
ufw allow https
ufw limit ssh
ufw enable
rc-update add ufw default
```

But I am not sure if I should be setting it's runlevel to `boot` so I am sure it starts before any other services  (ssh and docker (and therefor http/https services) are both set to start at `default`).

Does it matter? I don't believe alpine's RC system has a dependency setup like you might find in `systemd`.

Comment: Alpine uses OpenRC and its startup scripts are readable, so read the rc scripts and decide where it fits the best. BTW, Alpine uses ifupdown-ng which allows to run pre/post scripts when iface is activated/deactivated. See https://github.com/ifupdown-ng/ifupdown-ng/blob/master/doc/ifupdown-executor.scd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alpine preference is to use `awall`, Alpine `iptables` wrapper. And it uses *default* runlevel for `iptables` (`awall` generates `iptables` rules).

So, in most cased *default* runlevel is OK.

But see that your networking is activated in *boot* runlevel, so if you are paranoid just use *ifupdown-ng* pre/post scripts.

Comment: I think the question is mostly academic, unless you're a high value target that some how gets targeted *right between reboots*, if awall starts at default that's good enough for me!

Comment: Well, could be. For example OpenBSD starts its firewall (packet filter, PF) very early, before networking is enabled. See https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/etc/rc#L402. Then user defined rules are loaded little bit later, https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/etc/rc#L460.

Comment: That's quite clever.